# why do I get random characters when applying file handling in C

Tags: c, struct, file-handling

i tried to use fwrite to pass my struct to a txt file, but after i tried it the output printed in my txt file is random characters. I don't know if the problem is in my text editor(VS Code 1.76) or my device(Mac OS ).

check my github code for the entire code : https://github.com/fayzulhq/file-handling-for-public/commit/fca81c7868226f9b36787d32a6d76b59bef694f1

```
typedef struct staff
{
    char nama[20];
    char nim[10];
} staff;

typedef struct dosen
{
    staff dsn;
    unsigned long long int gaji;
    char matkul[20];
} dosen;

//...
void insert()
{
    char nama[20], nim[10];
    int status;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Masukkan nama :");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", nama);
    printf("Nim :");
    scanf("%10s", nim);
    puts("\nDosen.........1\n");
    puts("Mahasiswa.....2\n");
    printf("Status :");
    scanf("%d", &status);

    if (status == 1)
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("Dosen_kampus1.txt", "a");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            puts("Maaf file tidak dapat diakses!\n");
        }
        dosen new_dosen;

        char matkul[20];
        unsigned long long int gaji;
        printf("Masukkan Gaji : Rp");
        scanf("%llu", &gaji);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Mata kuliah : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", matkul);

        strcpy(new_dosen.dsn.nama, nama);
        strcpy(new_dosen.dsn.nim, nim);
        strcpy(new_dosen.matkul, matkul);
        new_dosen.gaji = gaji;

        fwrite(&new_dosen,sizeof(dosen),1,fp);

        fclose(fp);
        system("clear");
        puts("Data baru berhasil ditambahkan!\n");
    }
```

I hope that in my txt file, the contents of the struct can be printed neatly, and can be displayed on the terminal.

Comment: "fwrite to pass my struct to a txt file" That cannot work. `fwrite` writes raw memory content, no readable text. What do you expect, the bit pattern of an `unsigned long long` to look if viewed as text? You need `fprintf` if you deal with text files. Also: `fflush(stdin)` is invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: but, if I use FPRINTF, can I print the entire content of my individual struct? How?

Comment: You can printf the entire content of your struct with a series of individual format specifiers. One for each field. ;) If you want human readable output, you must specify how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `fwrite()`, the "raw" images of the memory is written to the file. There is no translation or conversion to text.

Among a lot of other alternatives, you can start to develop your solution with this suggestion.

```c
    fprintf(fp, "nama=%s\nnim=%s\ngaji=%llu\nmatkul=%s\n", new_dosen.dsn.nama, new_dosen.dsn.nim, new_dosen.gaji, new_dosen.matkul);
```

If you want, you can split the single `printf()` into multiple ones, for better overview and maintenance.

```c
    fprintf(fp, "nama=%s\n", new_dosen.dsn.nama);
    fprintf(fp, "nim=%s\n", new_dosen.dsn.nim);
    fprintf(fp, "gaji=%llu\n", new_dosen.gaji);
    fprintf(fp, "matkul=%s\n", new_dosen.matkul);
```

Please read the documentation of `fprintf()` of your system for details.

Comment: but when sya uses fprintf then sya can't display the entire contents of a certain individual struct... I want to create "search()" and "delete()" functions. I don't want to separate one struct from the other

Comment: @fyz08 (What is "sya"? Please don't use abbreviations, this is not a forum.) --  This is not what you ask in your question. As I wrote, use the answer as a starting point. -- If you have more issues, feel free to post separate questions. Just make sure you put some effort of your own to avoid closures. You might want to read some of the [help].